# Select first greater value than the x in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm working on an insurance comparison platform using Codeigniter.
I have a packages table which looks like this:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| tpckg_id | tpckg_people | tpckg_days | tpckg_policy_amount | tp_name     |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
|       21 | individual   | 10         | 1000                | Test25      |
|       22 | family       | 7          | 2000                | Testing     |
|       23 | individual   | 20         | 600                 | TPL Care    |
|       24 | family       | 10         | 1000                | TPL Care    |
|       25 | individual   | 15         | 650                 | Travel Care |
|       26 | family       | 10         | 1100                | TPL Care    |
|       27 | individual   | 7          | 500                 | TPL Care    |
|       28 | family       | 7          | 1200                | Travel Care |
|       29 | family       | 10         | 500                 | TPL Care 2  |
|       30 | individual   | 11         | 500                 | TPL Care    |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Now, I'm fetching the data using this query:

```
$this->db->select('travel_packages.tpckg_id, travel_packages.tpckg_people, travel_packages.tpckg_days, travel_packages.tpckg_policy_amount, travel_products.tp_name');

    $this->db->from('travel_packages');
    $this->db->join('travel_products', 'travel_products.tp_id = travel_packages.tpckg_products_id')

    $this->db->where('travel_packages.tpckg_people', 'Individual');
    $this->db->where('travel_packages.tpckg_days >= 10');

    $this->db->group_by('travel_packages.tpckg_policy_amount'); 
    $this->db->order_by('travel_packages.tpckg_policy_amount', 'ASC');
```

As expected is returns all the records which has tpckg_people = individual and tpckg_days >= 10 
like this:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| tpckg_id | tpckg_people | tpckg_days | tpckg_policy_amount | tp_name     |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
|       21 | individual   | 10         | 1000                | Test25      |
|       23 | individual   | 20         | 600                 | TPL Care    |
|       25 | individual   | 15         | 650                 | Travel Care |
|       30 | individual   | 11         | 500                 | TPL Care    |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

What I want it to return is only the first greater number of days if there's no equal number than what user has entered. For example if user enters 9 for number of days and I have no package with 9 number of days it should return the first greater number of days of each product.

Like this:

```
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
| tpckg_id | tpckg_people | tpckg_days | tpckg_policy_amount | tp_name     |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
|       21 | individual   | 10         | 1000                | Test25      |
|       25 | individual   | 15         | 650                 | Travel Care |
|       30 | individual   | 11         | 500                 | TPL Care    |
+----------+--------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+
```

Any help with the query, please? Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: As per your desired results I think first order by tpckg_policy_amount and then group by tp_name instead of tpckg_policy_amount you should get desired results....

Comment: Yes. Grouping by tpckg_policy_amount is decidedly odd

Comment: That's for a different purpose, to show the amount from low to high. I shouldn't have included it in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a raw query...

```
Select x.* 
  From travel_packages x
  Join
     ( Select tp_name name
            , tpckg_people people
            , min(tpckg_days) min_days 
         from travel_packages 
        where tpckg_people = 'individual' 
          and tpckg_days >= 9 
        group 
           by name
            , people
     ) y
    On y.name = x.tp_name
   And y.people = x.tpckg_people
   And y.min_days = x.tpckg_days;
```

Comment: It's not working since tp_name is actually not a part of the the same table. I am joining it with the travel_products table.
'JOIN travel_products ON travel_products.tp_id = travel_packages.tpckg_product_id'

How do I incorporate it in this query?

Comment: @RazaJ.Chauhan We can only answer the question that is asked. If you have a different question, start a separate thread, or amend your original question to reflect the correct situation.